# Unused local variable sonar issue inside java lambda

Tags: java, sonarqube, java-stream

Sonar is giving

> "Remove this unused addressId local variable"

error even though it is being used in my code.

```
    this.getStudentList()
            .forEach(student -> student.getAddressList().stream()
                    .filter(address -> AddressType.HOME.equals(address.getAddressType())
                            && address.isSelected())
                    .findFirst().ifPresent(address -> {
                        String addressId = null;
                        if (address.getAddress() != null) {
                            addressId = address.getAddress().getAddressId();
                        }
                        if (StringUtils.isEmpty(addressId) || addressId.equals(this.getAddress().getAddressId())) {
                            address.setAddress(student.getAddress());
                        } else {
                            address.setAddress(getAddressFromRemoteCall);
                        }
                    }));
```

Above code we can see that `addressId` is being used clearly but sonar is failing and giving error that

> Remove this unused "addressId" local variable

Can someone help me on this ?

Comment: Are you using the latest Java plugin ?https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarJava

Comment: Maybe related to https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-2958

Comment: You should really rethink this whole operation and your naming strategy; what is this address that has an address? How would you name the thing that `address.getAddress()` returns?

Comment: @Holger Indeed. It seems as though `address` holds some address metadata, plus the actual postal address data.

Comment: @Holger,@JimmyB  this is  an example to demonstrate my problem but whatever the usecase, sonar should not raise this error.

Comment: Well, the Sonar error might be formally wrong, but as long as it points you to code that really deserves rewriting, it actually does its job. In contrast, if you have simple and clean code that triggers the error as well, why didn’t you use that code to demonstrate the problem?